# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy - error in PHP website

Tags: caching, pagespeed

How to manage to Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy and minimize main-thread work.

[image: Serve static assets with an efficient cache]

Answer (score 2):

`Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy` - this is a suggestion that assets should have at least one month cache set on them (usually done via .htaccess).

It looks like you have already done this for everything you can control as the items listed are external assets you cannot set the cache policy on.

If you have done it for all your own resources (from your domain) then do not worry.

`minimise main-thread work` - this means that your site is using a LOT of JavaScript or performing a lot of calculations on page load.

The only way to improve this is to remove unnecessary JS and optimise anything that is remaining.

My guess is you are using lots of plugins / libraries to do simple things on the site that could more easily be achieved through other methods.

Post the URL of your site and I will improve this answer to give more relevant answers that may help you and others.

**Work around for efficient caching**

One way you could fix this issue (but you need to know what you are doing) is to download the script in question to your server every night via a cron job and serve it from your server instead.

That way you can set the cache time - however you need to make sure you do `cache busting` on the script each time you download a different version (by comparing the previous file and the new file and checking for changes) so you don't break functionality.

As you can imagine, this technique is only used in extreme circumstances where you can justify the need to control the cache policy due to the massively increased complexity and potential for problems.